# SQL query for date

Tags: mysql, sql

"How many orders were received in each month of 2000? Then order by each month ascending"

The date format for this question is `2000-01-00`. How would I query this so that orders would be separated by month and not stacked on top of each other?

Comment: You can `group by` a date part, `order by` thar group by clause, and use the year part in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can write below query:

if name of your column is startdate then

```
select month(startdate) monthofyear, 
       count(*) 
from   yourtable 
where  year(startdate) = 2000 
group by monthofyear 
order by monthofyear desc
```